# JNA and javaME error

Tags: java-me, jna, netbeans-8, unsupported-class-version

I'm trying to use JNA with javaME 8.2, but with no success. I'm new to both JNA and javaME.
I'm currently using NetBeans 8.1, javaME SDK 8.2 and JNA 4.2.1.

I have the following very simple test application that just creates an instance of the IntByReference JNA type:

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;

public class JavaMEApplication2 extends MIDlet {

boolean bFirst = false;
boolean loopFlag = true;

//@Override
public void startApp() {

    if (bFirst = false) {

        try {
            // Perform startup operations
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        bFirst = true;
    } else { 
        System.out.println("Trying starting IMlet...");
        IntByReference data = new IntByReference();
        System.out.println("IMlet Demo is already started...");
    }

    // Start program here
}
```

The code builds with no error, but when I try to execute it in the emulator (i'm using the default EmbeddedDevice emulator installed with the SDK) I got the following error.

```
Starting emulator in execution mode
Trying starting IMlet...
TRACE: <at java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError>, startApp threw an Exception
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError
 - javameapplication2/JavaMEApplication2.startApp(JavaMEApplication2.java:38)
 - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
 - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=5
 - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=236
 - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=38
 - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=5
 - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=127
 - com/sun/midp/main/AppIsolateMIDletSuiteLoader.main(), bci=26
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError
 - javameapplication2/JavaMEApplication2.startApp(JavaMEApplication2.java:38)
 - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=1
 - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=5
 - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=236
 - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=38
 - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=5
 - .unknown...unknown.(), bci=127
 - com/sun/midp/main/AppIsolateMIDletSuiteLoader.main(), bci=26
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

I know that you get a java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError when you compile a class with a JDK more recent than the one used for the execution, but this should not be the case.

Would anyone have an idea about what's happening here ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used JNA so I don't really know what it is, but the name implies that it's used to call native functionality on whatever device the MIDlet is running on.
I'm 99% sure that's simply not possible with JavaME, at least not when it comes to MIDlets.
If access to any native stuff would be available from JavaME, it would be if the device manufacturer had included such an API, in which case it wouldn't be called `com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference` but rather something like `com.vendor.jna.*`. I have never seen any examples of this though.